# How to save tkinter OptionMenu & Entry widgets' contents to a file?

Tags: python, python-3.x, widget, optionmenu

I am trying to save the user input from a optionmenu widget and entry widget on a file, the problem is the user input in entry widget is not being save properly. below is my code.

```
from tkinter import *                                                 

class ComputeTax:

    def __init__(self, master):

        self.compute_tax_frame = Frame(master)
        self.compute_tax_frame.pack()

        self.tax_status_label = Label(self.compute_tax_frame, text="input tax      status:")
        self.tax_status_label.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=E)
        self.status_option = StringVar(self.compute_tax_frame)
        self.status_option.set("S")
        self.tax_status_option = OptionMenu(self.compute_tax_frame,
                                            self.status_option, "S", "M", "M1", "M2", "M3", "M4",
                                            command=self.save_ts)
        self.tax_status_option.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky=W)

        self.monthly_salary_label = Label(self.compute_tax_frame, text="input    monthly pay:")
        self.monthly_salary_label.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky=E)
        self.salary_input = StringVar(self.compute_tax_frame)
        self.salary_input.set("0.00")
        self.monthly_salary_input = Entry(self.compute_tax_frame,
                                          textvariable=self.salary_input)
        self.monthly_salary_input.grid(row=1, column=1)

        self.calculate_button = Button(self.compute_tax_frame, text="Save &     Calculate now!")
        self.calculate_button.grid(row=3, columnspan=2)

    def save_ts(self, value):

        tax = value
        pay = self.salary_input.get()

        with open("monthly_net_pay", "w") as file:
            file.write("{}\n".format(tax))
            file.write("{}\n".format(pay))
            file.close()

frame = Tk()
a_compute_class = ComputeTax(frame)
frame.title("Monthly Tax & Net Pay Computation")
frame.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see a couple of problems with your code. The main one is that `OptionMenu` widgets don't have a `command` option/argument, so the `command=self.save_ts` doesn't accomplish anything (I'm a little surprised that no exception was raised from you attempting to specify it.)

The way to fix this is use the supply it when creating the `calculate_button`.

The second is that the `save_ts()` function expects a `value` argument, but one won't be passed to it. To correct that, first remove the parameter from the function `def` and instead get the needed value from the `Stringvar` widget you have named `status_option`.

Here's your code with the suggested fixes applied to it:

```
from tkinter import *

class ComputeTax:
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.compute_tax_frame = Frame(master)
        self.compute_tax_frame.pack()

        self.tax_status_label = Label(self.compute_tax_frame, 
                                      text="input tax status:")
        self.tax_status_label.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=E)
        self.status_option = StringVar(self.compute_tax_frame)
        self.status_option.set("S")
        self.tax_status_option = OptionMenu(self.compute_tax_frame,
                                            self.status_option,
                                            "S", "M", "M1", "M2", "M3", "M4")
        self.tax_status_option.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky=W)

        self.monthly_salary_label = Label(self.compute_tax_frame,
                                          text="input monthly pay:")
        self.monthly_salary_label.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky=E)
        self.salary_input = StringVar(self.compute_tax_frame)
        self.salary_input.set("0.00")
        self.monthly_salary_input = Entry(self.compute_tax_frame,
                                          textvariable=self.salary_input)
        self.monthly_salary_input.grid(row=1, column=1)

        self.calculate_button = Button(self.compute_tax_frame,
                                       text="Save & Calculate now!",
                                       command=self.save_ts)
        self.calculate_button.grid(row=3, columnspan=2)

    def save_ts(self):
        tax = self.status_option.get()
        pay = self.salary_input.get()
        with open("monthly_net_pay", "w") as file:
            file.write("{}\n".format(tax))
            file.write("{}\n".format(pay))
#            file.close()  # automatic when using `with`

frame = Tk()
a_compute_class = ComputeTax(frame)
frame.title("Monthly Tax & Net Pay Computation")
frame.mainloop()
```

Comment: P.S. I also wanted to compliment you on your otherwise well-coded tkinter application. BTW, [New Mexico Tech](http://www.nmt.edu/) has a good online [**_Tkinter reference_**](http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/index.html) you might find useful.

Comment: again thank you. Thank as well for the tip on accepting answers.